# Subclassing and extending numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, subclassing, multidimensional-array

I need some basic data class representations and I want to use existing numpy classes, since they already offer great functionality.

However, I'm not sure if this is the way to do it (although it works so far). So here is an example:

The `Position` class should act like a simple `numpy.array`, but it should map the attributes `.x`, `.y` and `.z` to the three array components. I overwrote the `__new__` method which returns an `ndarray` with the initial array. To allow access and modification of the array, I defined properties along with setters for each one.

```
import numpy as np


class Position(np.ndarray):
    """Represents a point in a 3D space

    Adds setters and getters for x, y and z to the ndarray.

    """
    def __new__(cls, input_array=(np.nan, np.nan, np.nan)):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        return obj

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self[0]

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self[0] = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self[1]

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self[1] = value

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self[2]

    @z.setter
    def z(self, value):
        self[2] = value
```

This seems however a bit too much code for such a basic logic and I'm wondering if I do it the "correct" way. I also need bunch of other classes like `Direction` which will have quite a few other functionalities (auto-norm on change etc.) and before I start integrating numpy, I thought I ask you…

Comment: So far, what you have looks a lot like a pandas.dataframe (not that I've worked with them myself ...).  Otherwise it looks pretty standard.

Comment: Which is more important to you, representing one point, or doing math with many thousands of points?  I'd start off working with `(N,3)` arrays (or `(3,N)`), and write a few functions to access selected columns.

Comment: The most important for me, is how to extend an `ndarray` correctly, as the title says. The `Position` is just a tiny example.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue ndarray is the wrong choice here, you probably want a simple namedtuple.

```
>>> import collections
>>> Position = collections.namedtuple('Positions', 'x y z')
>>> p = Position(1, 2, 3)
>>> p
Positions(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

You could get the unpacking like so

```
>>> x, y, z = p
>>> x, y, z
(1, 2, 3)
>>>
```

Comment: I really want the `ndarray` functionality, like dot product, matrix operations and all the other numpy extras. It would involve much more work to extend `namedtuple` to support them.

Comment: It depends on your cases, but named tuples was designed specifically for cases similar to the example you outlined above. I don't see how **view** functionality of numpy would be useful for a three items array. You could use normal python with map/reduce/comprehensions to deal with product, such as `Position(*map(lambda x: x * 3, p))`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html for more examples.

Comment: I've got hundreds of thousands of positions, directions and so on and many calculations along with matrix transformations in my analysis. Most of the algorithms require numpy arrays and that's why in my case it has to be numpy-like. Thanks for your answer, but this does not solve my special problem.

Comment: @septi: hundreds of thousands of 3-element numpy arrays is a recipe for slowness. If you care about performance, you need to reorganize your data into a few large numpy arrays, and ideally, express your calculations as being done on the large array as a whole. Otherwise, your code will actually be slower than using Python lists (or namedtuples).

Comment: I only wanted to emphasise that I'm already quite nested in a numpy environment. Of course, at some point there will probably be an optimisation process but at the moment I try to use whatever is "already there" and most of the stuff is linalg-operations on arrays. And btw. the 3D-Position is only an example. Thanks however.

Comment: I use bumpy heavily at work (with pandas), and the way we do this is to have an array for all Xs, another for Ys and another for Zs. This way, you have few numpy arrays (structs) with a single python wrapping header for each array. Remember bumpy is a mutable data structure, which means it has a dict, whereas a namedtuple uses slots to preserve memory, hence millions of named tuples are more efficient than hinder thousands of numpy arrays.

Comment: The `namedtuple` in this answer takes up 80 bytes, my subclassed numpy array `120`, and it has all the functionality I need in my algorithms. I don't care about performance yet.